# Picture in front of li elements

Tags: lightning, css, html, static-resources

I am trying to add a picture in front  of my li elements like they explain here: https://techforluddites.com/replacing-list-bullets-with-images-using-css/

I am having troubles with the documentation in my lightning components. How do I add a picture from my static resources? 
This is the css:

```
.THIS .li .checked {
 list-style-image: "{!$Resource.B2B_Partners_Checked}";
}
```

The path is correct but I am missing something like url= or src=. But how do note this down?

This is the html:

```
 <ul class="slds-list--dotted ">

                <li class="slds-p-around--x-small"> Minimum of 8 characters</li>
                <li class= "slds-p-around--x-small checked"> Minimum of 8 characters</li>
                <li class="slds-p-around--x-small"> At least one upper case character </li>
                <li class="slds-p-around--x-small"> At least one lower case character</li>
                <li class="slds-p-around--x-small"> At least one digit</li>

</ul>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already solved it:

```
 .THIS .checked {
  list-style-image: url(/resource/B2B_Partners_Checked);
}
```